# GWT/GAE 1MB .cache.js file is not gzip compressed

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, compression, gzip, split

I'm using GWT's splitting method to split the code into multiple fragments. My app is served by a Google App engine server and uses gzip compression to send the fragments.
The problem is that one of the fragments (left-over) of 1.1 MB (32.cache.js) is not being compressed. 
I used Chrome's dev tools (Network) and i noticed that the fragments that are compressed (24.cache.js for ex.) have the header "Content-Encoding:gzip" in the "Response headers" and the 1.1 MB file doesn't.

Why isn't that file compressed? Can it be a bug ? or do i have to make special settings to the gwt compiler or app engine server maybe?